# How to assign a sidebar to a Wordpress page when none was there before

Tags: sidebar

Hi and sorry for this possibly silly question. But how can I add a sidebar to a page in WP 5.6.2 that currently does not have a sidebar?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Steve

Comment: have you read https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/ ?

Comment: Hi Steve, and welcome! What page were you looking to add the sidebar to?